# JavaCV cvLoad return null

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, javacv, face-recognition

I'm using javaCV envelope in my project, and when I try to load Haar cascade from xml (`haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`) using `cvLoad` function I get null from it. Threre are no errors, just `null` instead of `Pointer`.

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.BytePointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.CvHaarClassifierCascade;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_objdetect.*;

URI haarCascadeResource = getClass().getResource(
                "/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml").toURI();
String haarCascadePath = Paths.get(haarCascadeResource).toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();    
Pointer pointerToCascade = cvLoad(haarCascadePath);
this.faceHaarCascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(pointerToCascade);
```

`pointerToCascade` is `null` and `this.faceHaarCascade` is also `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with code below:

```
Pointer pointerToCascade = cvLoad(Put the directory of the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml);
this.faceHaarCascade = new CvHaarClassifierCascade(pointerToCascade);
```